# Running video with applescript doesn't work

Tags: applescript

The following applescript is meant to open a video file using quicktime player from a file path but I'm not sure why it's not working as it comes up with vague yet menacing errors that are listed as "unknown." Please help fix it. Thanks.

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    set theMovie to open file ":Users:User:Desktop:Script:Video.mp4"
    tell theMovie
        set the presenting to true
        set the looping to true
        play
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

An HFS path must start with the name of a volume.

```
set theMovie to open file "Macintosh HD:Users:User:Desktop:Script:Video.mp4"
```

But there is a relative way

```
set moviePath to (path to desktop as text) & "Script:Video.mp4"
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    set theMovie to open file moviePath
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you, the code works great but only problem is the video doesn't play it just opens. I included play after the video opening section but it still didn't open.

Comment: nvm i fixed it myself